# How to access Hidden fields value inside Repeater control server side?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an repeater control which contains a hidden field, now I want to access the values of that hidden field by using either JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`HiddenField` control elements are rendered to inputs of type hidden.

```
$("input[type=hidden]")
```

Though your goal is not quite clear, But this could help you!

Answer (score 0):

### .aspx

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

### .aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.HiddenField1.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
}
```

### .js

```
window.onload=function(){
    var hiddenFieldObj=document.getElementById('HiddenField1');
    // code here 
};

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $hiddenField=jQuery('#HiddenField1');
    // code here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to your hidden control 
`<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" CssClass="selectHidden" runat="server" />`

then use 
$(".selectHidden") this will return all hidden controls